# How to setup ios platform through code with apple push notification p12 certificate file?

Tags: php, ios, onesignal

I want to create an app with ios platform set up from the .p12 file. How do I do that?

This is the method for creating app:

```php
class AppHandler
{
    public $USER_AUTH_KEY = 'Insert your key here';

    public function create($name, $apns_p12 = null, $apns_p12_password = null, $gcm_key = null, $android_gcm_sender_id = null)
    {
        $fields = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'apns_p12' => $apns_p12,
            'apns_p12_password' => $apns_p12_password,
            'gcm_key' => $gcm_key,
            'android_gcm_sender_id' => $android_gcm_sender_id
        );

        $fields = json_encode($fields);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/apps");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
            "Authorization: Basic " . $this->USER_AUTH_KEY));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        try {
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            if (!$response) {
                throw new Exception("App wasn't created");
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        } finally {
            curl_close($ch);
        }

        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        $return = array(
            'id' => $response['id'],
            'basic_auth_key' => $response['basic_auth_key']
        );

        return $return;
    }
...
```

And this is the method with 2 ways of getting the insides of .p12 file:

```php
    public function getP12($pkcs12, $password = NULL): string
    {

        /*
        // Way 1:
        $pkcs12 = file_get_contents($pkcs12);
        $encoded = base64_encode($pkcs12);

        return $encoded;
        */

        // Way 2:
        $cert_store = file_get_contents($pkcs12);
        if (!$cert_store) {
            echo "Error: can't read file.\n";
            exit;
        }

        $pkcs12Read = openssl_pkcs12_read($cert_store, $cert_info, $password);
        if ($pkcs12Read) {
            $result = base64_encode($cert_info['cert']);
            return $result;
        } else {
            echo "Error: can't read cert.\n";
            exit;
        }
    }
```

According to [onesignal's doc](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-an-app) I have to send apns_p12 as *my apple push notification p12 certificate file, converted to a string and Base64 encoded*.

And I do that this way:

```php
$obj = new AppHandler();
$response = $obj->create('TestName', $obj->getP12('cert.p12', 'password'), 'password')
```

It creates an app with given name, however, the platform is not set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I simply needed to add apns_env parameter:

```php
$fields = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'apns_env' => $apns_env,
            'apns_p12' => $apns_p12,
            'apns_p12_password' => $apns_p12_password,
            'gcm_key' => $gcm_key,
            'android_gcm_sender_id' => $android_gcm_sender_id
        );
```

And I should've taken insides of the file and converted them to a string and Base64 encoded like that:

```php
public function getP12($pkcs12): string
    {
        $apns_12 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($pkcs12));

        return $apns_12;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "the platform is not set up"? What error are you getting and where?

By the way, I finally gave up trying code the intricacies of APNS programming and instead went with AWS' Simple Notification Service: https://aws.amazon.com/sns. It handles both Apple and Google notifications by using the API to set up topics and subscribers, plus you can send up to 1 million notifications per month free.